# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning after clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, cleartimeout

If I clear the timer after it has rejected the promise - I get a warning "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" in stdout regardless of whether I intercept 'catch' on the promise or not

checked on: node v10, node v12, google-chrome  76

```js
let timer;
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('!timeout');
        reject('timeout error');
    });
}, 100);

promise.then(result => {
    console.log('SUCCESS:', result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('!onerror');
    console.error('ERROR:', error);
});

promise.finally(() => {
    console.log('!onfinnaly');
    clearTimeout(timer);
});

console.log('!endcode');
```

console output in nodejs:

```
!endcode
!timeout
!onfinnaly
!onerror
ERROR: timeout error
(node:12697) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: timeout error
(node:12697) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:12697) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

console output in google-chrome:

```
!endcode
!timeout
!onfinnaly
!onerror
ERROR: timeout error
Promise.catch (async)
Uncaught (in promise) timeout error
```

Comment: are you sure that ```promise``` is the timer or is your variable called ```timer``` the timer, because in your code you are saying ```clearTimeout(promise)```

Comment: Your `100` value is in the wrong place. (should be the second argument to `setTimeout`

Comment: Please forgive me! This is a missprint!
Of course, I meant `clearTimeout (timer)`

Comment: @user3410504 Updates/edits based on comments should preferably be reflected in the question itself. This way other readers don't have to weed out the whole comment section. You find the [*edit*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57503001/edit) option under the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call [Promise#finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) on a Promise that is rejected, the Promise returned by finally is also rejected:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', _ => console.error( 'Unhandled Rejection' ) );

Promise.reject( )
  .finally( _ => _ );
```

If you might be calling finally on a rejected Promise, you still need to catch the error to prevent an unhandled rejection:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', _ => console.error( 'Unhandled Rejection' ) );

Promise.reject( 'foobar' )
  .finally( _ => _ )
  .catch( e => console.log( 'Caught: ' + e ) );
```

If you chain your finally after the `catch`, instead of calling it directly on your `promise`, you would not have an unhandled rejection, because catch returns a Promise that will be fulfilled (unless a new error is thrown or a rejected Promise is returned from the catch callback).

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now everything is clear